# Speed up execution time of JSON-ification and processing of data with Python

Tags: python, json

My script looks like this:

```
with open('toy.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    lines = [json.loads(line) for line in inpt]

    for line in lines: 
        records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]
    for item in records: 
        print item
```

What it does is read in data where each line is valid JSON, but the file as a whole is *not* valid JSON. The reason for that is because it's an aggregated dump from a web service.

The data looks, more or less, like this:

```
{"record":"value0","block":"0x79"} 
{"record":"value1","block":"0x80"}
```

So the code above works, it allows me to interact with the data as JSON, but it's so slow that it's essentially useless.

Is there a good way to speed up this process?

**EDIT:**

```
with open('toy.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    for line in inpt:
        print("identifier: "+json.loads(line)['identifier'])
        print("value:  "+json.loads(line)['value'])
```

**EDIT II:**

```
for line in inpt:
    resource = json.loads(line)
    print(resource['identifier']+", "+resource['value'])
```

Comment: Why do you construct `records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]` for each line?

Comment: so I can access the item by it's JSON identifier and also so I can iterate over the whole file

Comment: but you never use `line` in the list comprehension, an in the list comprehension, you iterate already over `lines` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

```
for line in lines: 
    records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]
```

But this means that you will construct that `records` list **n times** (with *n* the number of lines). This is useless, and makes the time complexity *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

You can speed this up with:

```
with open('toy.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    for item in [json.loads(line)['hash'] for line in inpt]:
        print item
```

Or you can reduce the memory burden, by each time priting the hash when you process a line:

```
with open('toy.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    for line in inpt:
        print json.loads(line)['hash']
```

Comment: excellent. thank you for these insights. Can't accept the answer till 9 minutes later, but I will as soon as I can.

Comment: this `json.loads(line)['gas'] for line in inpt` is totally awesome- do you have some resource where I can learn about that?

Comment: in the edit I made some way of printing an identifier along with the value, do you think it's an ok approach?

Comment: @s.matthew.english: well here you parse the JSON code twice, furthermore the dictionaries have no `'identifier'` or `'value'` key.

Comment: @s.matthew.english: `jdon.loads(line)` returns a dictionary (like in your piece in code). You can simply chain operations. By writing `['hash']` we access the `hash` key of the dictionary, so we put that one in the list.

Comment: @s.matthew.english: see [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: cool- thank you for the resrouce, and also- I think I see what you mean, I put the new version in **EDIT II**

Comment: @s.matthew.english: but your data looks like `{"record":"value0","block":"0x79"}`. That means every dictionary has **two keys**: `record` and `block`. In case the dictionaries have keys like `identifier`, and `value`, your second edit is ok.

Comment: oh yeah- it has two keys, actually it has like 20 key values per line of JSON, but I'm only interested in two of them, it's more like one is a hash, and the value associated with that hash, the next is one characteristic, and the value of that characteristic, you know what I mean?

Comment: @s.matthew.english: yes, in that case it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is print and you are dealing with massive files you can split your file into `n` evenly sized chunks where n == number of cores in your CPU.